# How do I allocate GCHandle to structure when structure contains array?

Tags: c#, dllimport

I have a structure:

```
public struct ResultOfStrategy
{
    ......
    public double[] param;
    public IntPtr ptr;
}
```

I will put this structure in DLL and it is necessary to return values of an array in the structure

```
result = new ResultOfStrategy[(int)length];

for(int i = 0; i < (int)length; i++)
{
    result[i].param = new double[10];
}

// try... finally trick to be sure that the code isn't interrupted by asynchronous exceptions
try
{

}
finally
{
    handle = GCHandle.Alloc(result, GCHandleType.Pinned);
}

return handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

I get an error - The object contains data that are not primitives or require conversion. How to fix this problem?

P.s. I want to pass in C++ from C# an array of a structure in which there will be ordinary variables and 1 array of type double.

Comment: You have a XY problem... Even if result would be pinnable, the array `param` wouldn't be pinned... And you don't have any guarantee that it would be converted to a `double *param;`... Better that you make a question about what you want to pass to C/what you want to retrieve from C and see how other persons would solve it.

Comment: @xanatos thank you for answer, i corrected my question

Comment: It is not very likely to be a match with the C++ declaration, we can't see it.  Only a UnmanagedType.ByValArray or a fixed buffer can be marshaled.  In other words, a double[10] in the C++ declaration.  If it is truly a double* in the C++ declaration then you must use IntPtr in the C# declaration.  And worry a good deal about the C++ code having no real idea how large the array might be, coloring outside of the lines produces GC heap corruption.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, BUT, there is a single certain thing: you can't easily pin the `ResultOfStrategy` struct. So you have to create a copy of that `struct`...

```
public struct ResultOfStrategy
{
    public IntPtr ptr;
    public double[] param;
}

public struct ResultOfStrategyImpl
{
    public IntPtr ptr;
    public IntPtr param;
}

public static IntPtr Test(int length, out GCHandle[] handlesToBeFreed)
{
    var result = new ResultOfStrategy[(int)length];

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)length; i++)
    {
        result[i].param = new double[10];
    }

    // Copy to new blittable object
    var result2 = new ResultOfStrategyImpl[result.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        result2[i].ptr = result[i].ptr;
    }

    handlesToBeFreed = new GCHandle[length + 1];

    GCHandle handle;

    // try... finally trick to be sure that the code isn't interrupted by asynchronous exceptions
    try
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            handle = GCHandle.Alloc(result2[i], GCHandleType.Pinned);
            handlesToBeFreed[i] = handle;
            result2[i].param = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        }

        handle = GCHandle.Alloc(result2, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        handlesToBeFreed[result.Length] = handle;
    }

    return handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
}

public static void FreeHandles(GCHandle[] handles)
{
    if (handles != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < handles.Length; i++)
        {
            handles[i].Free();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
GCHandle[] handlesToBeFreed = null;

try
{
    IntPtr ptr = Test(10, out handlesToBeFreed);

    // Work with ptr
}
finally
{
    FreeHandles(handlesToBeFreed);
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. This is big help for me. I'll test this version and i'll write you